# Tumblr, Create a new post with Tumblr API

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, tumblr

I'm trying to create a new post with Tumblr API.

Here is the request header I send to the server:

```
POST /v2/blog/{blogname}/post HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth 
oauth_consumer_key="consumer_key goes here", 
oauth_nonce="pec35558",    
oauth_signature="6DZUaf8wlEZsOBWLUd0UTZMe1Eo%3D", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1455963512", 
oauth_token="access_token goes here", 
oauth_version="1.0"
Host: api.tumblr.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Is it right? And what should be inserted into request header above to create a new text post?

I took a look into https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting but have no idea how to insert parameters into the request header.

I inserted:

```
 type: text&title=OK&body=OK
```

into the header above but server return

> 5b {"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":{"errors":["Post cannot be empty."]}} 0

A request header example would be great!

Comment: Am having the same issue. Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: Hi @Bhargav I used Java SDK instead since nobody answered the question